# Use VOIP through small switch

Tags: voip

Probably a silly question but I have to ask. I don't know much about VOIP. We have a location with a large room now being used as an office for 2 people. There is one network cable ran to this office. Can I just use a simple 4 port switch to connect 2 VOIP phones to the single cable run? Would be much cheaper than to run another cable.

Comment: Remember most VOIP phones can pass through ethernet. So you likely can CHAIN one phone to the next. You do not even need a switch ;) This is normally meant so that on a desk you can have one phone and then plus the computer network into it - because most desks have only one ethernet port ;)

Comment: That's what they are doing in most of the locations, pc->phone->wall.

Comment: What do the size and port count of the switch have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a tiny network it is acceptable to have the VOIP on the same equipments and VLAN as the rest of the network. As the company grows you will want to have the VOIP traffic in a separate VLAN. This means managed switches, QOS...

Comment: As far as I know, this locations voice/data traffic is separated at the firewall. It is however a very small office with 6 phones. Thanks for your help.